# Continuously run MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, architecture, aggregation-framework

I have an ETL pipeline that is sinking timeseries records to MongoDB.

I need to compute timely aggregations for daily, weekly and the like. I assumed the aggregations engine of MongoDB would be the way to go, so after I had the aggregation queries for each resolution I wrapped them with MongoDB views like "daily_view", "weekly_view", etc.

There is REST service to fetch from MongoDB. Depending on what period resolution is requested, it pulls from the different aforementioned views, sampling for start and end dates.

The **response times** are quite "poor" with these views/aggregations. It can be around 10-15 seconds. I take this lapse might not be outrageous for batch computing a report, but in my case the service needs to issue these requests in a live mode to serve the frontend, so 10 seconds wait is too much.

From the MongoDB reference I know that `Views are computed on demand during read operations` but I'm a bit disappointed with such response times because the same aggregations took split seconds in Elasticsearch or InfluxDB, which unfortunately are not an option for me at the moment.
I have also exhausted the research about optimizing the queries and there is no room from more improvement there than the way it already is.

My intuition tells me that if the aggregations have to be done via the aggregations engine, I need the pipelines executing continuously on the fly (so the views have records already in for the service), as opposed to be run everytime ad-hoc.

I've tried to drop the views, and instead have and aggregation with a last stage being an $out to a real collection ...but I have still the same problem, it needs to be run "on demand". I composed the pipelines using the Compass UI, and in the $out stage it presents a button to run the aggregation.

**Would there be a way to schedule such pipelines/aggregation queries??**

Something I can think about is, copy-pasting the code of the aggregations and make it into Javascript functions of the REST service ...but still, something would have to invoke those functions on a regular interval. I know there are libraries I can bring into the service for scheduling, but this option makes me feel a bit discomforted in terms of architecture.

In the worst case scenario, my backup plan is to implement the timely aggregations as part as the logic of the initial ETL and sink all the different resolutions to different collections, so the service will find records to fetch already waiting in the aggregated collections. But the intention was to leverage time aggregations to the datastore engine.

I'm having a bit of last minute architecture distress now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$out` aggregation stage. [Documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

> Takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection. The $out operator must be the last stage in the pipeline.

`$mongo` accepts javascript file as an argument. So this is the easiest way to package your aggregation. [Reference.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo)

```
mongo file.js --username username --password
```

Then - to execute it on schedule - common tools like cron jobs to the rescue.

You might need to account for the differences between Mongo Shell and Javascrips such as using `db = db.getSiblingDB('<db>')` instead of `use <db>`. [Write Scripts for the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)